# Imperatives of derivatives of facere, dicere and ducere

Tags: verbs, irregular-words, imperative, prefix, compound-verb

Three verbs are well known to have an irregular short imperative: *fac*, *dic*, *duc*.
Do the imperatives remain short in the presence of a prefix?
For example, which ones are correct out of *effic/effac/effice*, *interdic/interdice*, *adduc/adduce*?
My impression is that they are almost always in their usual long form if there is a prefix, but there are some exceptions.
For some reason I feel that I should undo vowel gradation if I use a short imperative; *effac* sounds better than *effic*.

Is there a rule or guideline for the imperatives of *facere*, *dicere* and *ducere* with prefixes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To supplement Tom Cotton's answer—

There's one other verb which similarly shortens its imperative: *ferō, ferre, tulī, lātus*, imperative *fer, ferte*. Compounds always use the shortened/apocopated form (*adfer*/*adferte*, *offer*/*offerte* etc), with **adfere* / **adferete*, **offere* / **offerete* etc entirely absent from the PHI corpus.

So these two seem relatively certain: compounds of *facere* have regular imperatives (as Tom explains), while compounds of *ferre* have shortened ones. *Dīce* and *dūce* are less clear-cut.

For compounds of *dūcere*, the regular/long imperatives are almost exclusively found in Plautus, where they actually appear more frequently than the shortened forms: the PHI corpus (when restricted to Plautus) lists 7 occurrences of *addūce* and 7 of *abdūce*, but only one of *addūc* and three of *abdūc*.

In later authors, compounds using *dūce* are much less common: ten instances of *prodūc* compared to zero of *prodūce*. (Both *addūc* and *abdūc* become rare, though still more common than *addūce* and *abdūce*.)

For *dīcere*, imperatives in compounds are extremely rare in general. *Aeneid* 11.463 contains one notable instance of *ēdīce*, which is marked as unusual in Honoratus's *Commentary*:

> 'edice' autem plenus est imperativus; nam ab omnium coniugationum infinito detracta 're' ultima syllaba fit imperativus, ut 'amare ama', 'docere doce', 'legere lege', 'audire audi'. cum autem 'fac' vel 'dic' dicimus, apocopen verba patiuntur. ex 'face' 'dice' conposuit 'edice'. expressa autem festinantis oratio, quia Turnum non praedixit locuturum.

Translation:

> *ēdīce* however is a full imperative; for the imperative of every conjugation is formed by removing the final syllable *-re* from the infinitive, thus *amāre - amā*, *legere - lege*, *audīre - audī*. When, however, we say *fac* or *dīc*, the verbs undergo *apocope*. *Ēdīce* is composed from *face* or *dīce*. However, this is the rushed speech of someone in a hurry, because he did not mention Turnus being ready to speak.

Plautus even uses *dīce* and *dūce* [as imperative of *dūcere*, not ablative singular of *dŭx*] on occasion, which I can't find anywhere else, though he still prefers *dīc* and *dūc*: *dīc* appears 121 times, *dīce* 12. So the regularized *-e* imperatives may have been colloquial or dialectal forms which were dying out in Plautus's time, and disappeared almost entirely by the Classical era.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of fero, which I'd quite overlooked. I wonder how many other, similar cases there are!

Comment: Expanded. Hopefully this is more helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! One small comment: The noun *dux* has a short U in all forms, so *dŭce* (ablative) and *dūce* (imperative) are distinguishable if quantity is known.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Ah, how I wish now for a corpus with macrons! That would be a much easier way to distinguish the two; my strategy here was eyeballing the context to see if it was verb-like or noun-like. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Generally, verbs of mixed 3rd/4th conjugation and their compounds (inf. -*ere*, 1st. pres. sing. in -*io*) all follow the same pattern, which includes compounds of *facio*, but **not** *facio* itself — which means that *effice*, etc. are the correct forms. *Fac* is a peculiarity.

Unlike those of *facio*, the compounds of *dico* and *duco* mainly follow the pattern of the simple verbs, including the abbreviated imperatives. There are one or two exceptions, such as the occurrence of *adduce* for *adduc* and *dice* for *dic*, though my impression is that they are most often pre-classical. The compounds usually fall into the 3rd conjugation, but there may be exceptions: *indico*, for example, is a completely regular 1st conjugation verb with the imperatives *indica*, *indicato*, and so on.

Comment: You say this as if it was instinctive, which of course it is after a time. But did you have to look it up at all?

Comment: And speaking *meta,* this is a really useful set of misc information to have all in one place. Ideal SE.

Comment: @Hugh I'm not sure that 'instinctive' is the right word, but I simply wrote it as I remember after years of translating from and into Latin.

Answer (score 6):

As Weiss 2009/2011 mentions, word-final –e is “**normally retained**” (p. 147; emphasis mine – Alex B.). That being said, there are some few cases when word-final –e was lost (or apocopated).

In your question, **you ask us specifically about the imperatives of the compound verbs** of *dico*, *duco*, and *facio*. In my answer below I will address this issue only. If you are interested in imperatives of simplex dico, duco, facio, and fere; how to interpret data from Archaic Latin (Plautus and **other authors**), I’ll be happy to share my thoughts as well.

Now, revenons à nos moutons.

First, **facio**. Based on whether the root vowel is changed or not, the derivatives of facio can be grouped into two classes:

**Type A. calefacio** [root vowel preserved], compound verbs (two roots).

**Type B. conficio** [root vowel weakened], prefixed verbs.

However, **the 2nd singular imperative** of both types is formed the same way: calface! confice! areface!

Secondly, **dico**. Weiss argues that compound 2nd singular imperatives from dico are not attested in Classical Latin.

Finally, **duco** and **fere**. Apocopated forms are standard in Classical Latin:

*confer! infer!*

Apocopated means that originally they had –e at the end (in fact, such forms are attested) but eventually it was lost. Note that there are no root vowel changes in these compounds. Another strong evidence in support of this analysis comes from accentology. **Such apocopated singular imperatives are oxytones**, i.e. the last syllable is stressed:

*edúc!*

> **The most interesting question** that has not been addressed in the other answers – even though you clearly ask us – **is how we know when the root vowel changes or not.**

Weiss discusses it on pp. 121-122 (footnote 25, citing Garrett 2005 and Pultrova 2006).

**Back root vowel** [no change in compounds]: duco – adduco, educo etc. and, respectively, adduc, educ etc.

**More diverse morphology** [vowel weakening, a changes to i]: facio – conficio and its 2 sg. imperative confice.

To recap (based on Weiss),

> Imperatives from compounds of **duco** and **fero**: short (apocopated) forms, e.g. *educ! effer!*
>
> Imperatives from compounds of **dico**: not attested in Classical Latin<sup>1</sup>
>
> Imperatives from compounds of **facio**: unapocopated forms, e.g. *calface! confice!*

<sup>1</sup> cf. Neue and Wagener 1902 (p. 306), who mention two attestations of the unapocopated forms for Classical Latin, Cicero Pro Sestio 37 *male dic Titio* and Petronius 96,7 *maledic illam versibus*.

Comment: Re archaic: PHI lists 121 instances of *dīc* in Plautus's work, compared with 12 of *dīce*. So the apocopated form was already preferred for the uncompounded verbs.

Comment: @Draconis let's not get sidetracked here. The OP is about **imperatives of compound verbs**. But thanks, I'll look into this later.

Comment: Indeed. I just find it interesting (and relevant) that Plautus **preferred *-e* for compounds but no *-e* for the base words**, which might indicate how the apocopated imperatives evolved or show some sort of hypercorrection; unfortunately, I don't know enough about the historical context to do more than speculate on that front.

Comment: @Draconis Sorry, cannot comment on that. Need time and more data. So far, I'll stick to "seem". Willing to make changes later.

Comment: BTW do you know the source for the oxytone accentuation of *educ* etc.? I'm guessing this is mentioned by some ancient author, but don't know which one.

Comment: Does Weiss not consider [Petronius](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=maledic%23) a Classical author?

Comment: @TKR I'll do some research and will update my answer if I find anything. So far, I have seen the apocopated forms with a circumflex, see Probert 2019: 226-228, she quotes some relevant passages from Paperinus and Priscian.

Comment: @cmw my guess is that because, unlike the other compound dico verbs, maledico could be rather tricky, it could be either a compound verb maledico or male dico (a simplex verb), there are some interesting examples in the TLL entry, "Ante hos sex menses **male**” ait “**dixisti** mihi.”' or male non dicas etc. But this is just my guess.

Comment: @AlexB. You beat me to it. I was just going to suggest that maybe it's not supposed to be read together in Petronius. But the Phaedrus example could also be tmesis. I do find it odd though that it's so prevalent in Plautus and then stops for a couple hundred years (or else is just by chance not represented in literature from the Classical period).

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, but I wanted to point out that at least *tābefac* is attested, in the Vulgate no less:

> da illis formidinem et **tabefac** audaciam virtutis eorum et commoveantur contritione sua
>
> Strike them with fear, and **cause** the boldness of their strength **to languish**, and let them quake at their own destruction.

(https://vulgate.org/ot/1machabees_4.htm)

Perhaps the Latin mind naturally conceptualised this verb as *tābe faciō* (i.e. two words).

**Edit:** After some smarter searching, I found that *benefac* "bless!" is especially widespread, occurring 8 times in the Vulgate and appearing in all kinds of other early Christian texts. The only other compound *-fac* imperative attested in pre-Medieval Latin is *olefac*, used once by Augustine of Hippo, a variant spelling of *olfac* "smell!". None of these forms appear in Classical Latin.

Comment: Welcome to the site!